# Eclipse Modeling Framework - cannot load plugin.xml

Tags: xml, plugins, emf, eclipse-jet

I have been following this tutorial:

http://www.vogella.com/articles/EclipseEMF/article.html

I cannot deal with Step

> 5.2. Run your plugins

I'm trying to open plugin.xml file but it gives me an error:

> Unsupported Content in Editor

Answer (score 0):

The Android SDK believes that it is one of its files then, when it tries to open it, it crashes since it does not contain what it was expected. Right click on the file plugin.xml and select "Open With" and then the "Plug-in Manifest Editor".